# Dúvida sobre width da página, display none e tamanho (MB)

Tags: html, css

1. Existe um *width* ideal para uma página web?
2. Quando colocamos uma imagem com `display: none`, a imagem é carregada juntamente com o carregamento da página ou quando clicamos sobre ela?
3. Qual é o tamanho (MB) considerado "leve" para um site?

Comment: Porque tantos votos negativos  se a pergunta é pertinente, não entendi essa galera da comunidade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 -** Dê uma olhado sobre `design responsivo`, sobre a largura, a ideal é `100%`, sempre sua página terá essa largura, mas o seu conteúdo deve ter essa largura também para preencher toda a área:

```
width: 100%;
```

**2 -** O `none`no `display` apenas oculta o elemento na página, ela é carregada normalmente no momento em que aquela página é requerida.

**3 -** Não há um tamanho ideal para site, pois o peso dele pode ser por exemplo `40MB`, mas não quer dizer que o cliente irá carregar todos esse tamanho e sim apenas a página que ele está acessando e suas depedências.

Comment: quem é esse webmaster que vai fazer um pagina com 40mb kkk, acho que @Ney quis dizer 40kb

Comment: Ele quis dizer um site inteiro, não somente uma página, repare na resposta, disse que independentemente do tamanho do site ele não será totalmente carregado, mas sim a página atual e suas dependências.

Comment: eu entende so ironizei o fato se for contar font-end com back-end pode dar ate mais dependendo do tamanho do site

Comment: e para pagina qual o tamanho considerado leve?

Comment: Não há muito um padrão mano, nao tenho certeza pra mim seria algo entre 1-2,5MB (contando com arquivos de imagens etc que são dependências da página). Mas não tenho certeza disso, é algo difícil de dizer.

Comment: um site "leve" de 1MB pode ser mais pesado para carregar que um site de  10MB. A forma de programar influí na velocidade do carregamento.

Comment: Nem tanto exagero kk a forma de programar pode influenciar desde que o site possua uma base de dados e o desenvolvedor não saiba usar a mesma, além disso quando se usa muito conteúdo externo.